# UglifyJS продожает работать после удаления

Tags: webpack

Здравствуйте.
Был установлен UglifyJS (WebPack3).  Я экспериментирую и он мне не нужен - я его закоментил. А он всё равно продолжает работать. Сделал 
npm cache clean -f и тольку ноль.
Подскажите где он так закэширован и как его в таких ситуациях "выгонять"?

Comment: Вебпак с какого-то момента (со второй версии кажется) с флагом "-p" запускает углифай всегда, потому и работает, как воркараунд запускать без флага -p и отдавать node_env дефайн плагину ручками если вам надо

Comment: По типу webpack --define process.env.NODE_ENV=\"production\". Обычно webpack -p делает именно это плюс углифай, чтобы сказать точно надо глянуть в исходники используемой версии

Comment: да, действительно так, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

С 3-ей версии в настройках вебпака появился параметр mode. Он указывает, в каком режиме сейчас будет работать вебпак.

Есть два режима: development и production.

В production, вебпак сам добавляет UglifyPlugin. Сделано это из-за того, что с теперь вебпак можно запускать даже без файла конфигурации, а просто указав пару параметров в аргументах его вызова.